# javafx shapes, bind coordinate values, performance issue, how to remove from scene

Tags: javafx

Here is a boiled down version of my intended application. Run this code on JavaFX 15.0.1, you will see a window displaying a bunch of blue lines and dots, and a reload button. Rotate the mouse wheel to zoom in and out of the picture.

Problem is:
Click the "reload" button about 20 times, then rotate the mouse wheel. Observe how the application freezes for seconds, sometimes cpu activitiy will reach 90%. If nothing suspicious, click for some more reloads.

So I believe the problem is how to remove all the shapes and bindings from the scene, this must be the reason of degrading performance, right? I do a `pane.getChildren().clear();` Am I missing something here?

```
package application;
    
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    private DoubleProperty zoom = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    private int w = 800;
    private int h = 500;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Button reload = new Button("reload");
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.setManaged(false);
            
            reload.setOnAction(event -> {
                pane.getChildren().clear();
                List<Displacement> disList = Stream.generate(Displacement::new).limit(1200).collect(Collectors.toList());;
                disList.forEach(dis -> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementLine(dis, w, h, pane)));
                disList.forEach(dis -> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementCircle(dis, w, h, pane)));
            });
            
            VBox vbox = new VBox(reload, pane);
            Pane root = new Pane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            root.getChildren().add(vbox);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setWidth(1000);
            stage.setHeight(600);
            stage.show();
            
            pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(zoom.multiply(w));
            pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(zoom.multiply(h));
            pane.layoutXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().subtract(pane.prefWidthProperty()).divide(2.0));
            pane.layoutYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().subtract(pane.prefHeightProperty()).divide(2.0));
            
            pane.setOnScroll(scrollEvent -> {
                double delta = 0.1;
                double f = scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 1+delta : 1/(1+delta);
                zoom.set(zoom.get() * f);
            });
            
            reload.fire();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class DisplacementLine extends Line {

    final int w, h;
    final double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    
    public DisplacementLine(Displacement dis, int w, int h, Pane pane) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        x1 = dis.x;
        y1 = dis.y;
        x2 = dis.x + dis.u;
        y2 = dis.y + dis.v;
        startXProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty().multiply(x1).divide(w));
        startYProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty().multiply(y1).divide(h));
        endXProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty().multiply(x2).divide(w));
        endYProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty().multiply(y2).divide(h));
        setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(dis.valid);
    }
}

class DisplacementCircle extends Circle {

    final int w, h;
    final double x, y;
    
    public DisplacementCircle(Displacement dis, int w, int h, Pane pane) {
        this.x = dis.x;
        this.y = dis.y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        centerXProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty().multiply(x).divide(w));
        centerYProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty().multiply(y).divide(h));
        setRadius(1.5);
        setFill(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(dis.valid);
    }
}

class Displacement {

    final static Random rand = new Random();
    final double x, y, u, v;
    final boolean valid;
    
    public Displacement() {
        x = rand.nextDouble() * 1000;
        y = rand.nextDouble() * 600;
        u = rand.nextDouble() * 30;
        v = rand.nextDouble() * 15;
        valid = rand.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

[image: app window]

Comment: Could you just redraw listening on the pref height / width properties and then not needing the properties inside DisplacementLine? Other thing try garbage collecting after clearing the children. It also could be that all those bound objects are not actually being removed when you clear the children due to the bindings. Finally instead of bindings, maybe use a transofrm on the pane? http://johnthecodingarchitect.blogspot.com/2013/11/scaling-vs-zooming-in-javafx.html

Comment: that's a nice idea, implemented that in a quick way. There is no more lag or freeze. So comparing these two codes very much shows that bindings somehow are still leftover when the objects containing those bindings are no more part of the scene.

Comment: @geometrikal and OP: removing the nodes from panes makes them eligible for gc but the listeners (though weakly registered via bindings) are still lingering until a) gc actually happens _and_ b) the observed value actually changes. Here it means that the listeners to f.i. pane.pref pile up on clicking the button (1200 per property per action), then when pref changes (via zoom) all those listeners are notified: at the best, the bound objects are already gc'ed and the listeners remove themselves - at the worst, they go through the loops ..

Comment: @geometrikal and OP: there are reported issues (closed as wontfix), see https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/wiki/Memory-Leaks for an incomplete summary (section Cleanup after themselves)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks, I never quite knew why some things lingered around and b) explains it. Another thing that is hard and can cause problems is nested bindings. .NETs binding system is a bit better IMO as it listens for messages rather than connecting to specific instances.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by [geometrical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31045/geometrikal) I put together this variation. That looks very nice to mee, I can sill have immutable objects this way.

Here I introduced functions to listen for a change to pane width / height properties and then set the coordinates of each shape, so no thousands of bindings are created.

Will adapt this to my final project

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    private DoubleProperty zoom = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    private int w = 800;
    private int h = 500;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Button reload = new Button("reload");
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.setManaged(false);
            
            Consumer<Number> setX = value -> {
                double pw = value.doubleValue();
                for (Node node : pane.getChildren()) {
                    if (node instanceof DisplacementLine) {
                        DisplacementLine dl = (DisplacementLine) node;
                        dl.setStartX(pw * dl.x1 / w);
                        dl.setEndX(pw * dl.x2 / w);
                    }
                    if (node instanceof DisplacementCircle) {
                        DisplacementCircle dc = (DisplacementCircle) node;
                        dc.setCenterX(pw * dc.x / w);
                    }
                }
            };
            Consumer<Number> setY = value -> {
                double ph = value.doubleValue();
                for (Node node : pane.getChildren()) {
                    if (node instanceof DisplacementLine) {
                        DisplacementLine dl = (DisplacementLine) node;
                        dl.setStartY(ph * dl.y1 / h);
                        dl.setEndY(ph * dl.y2 / h);
                    }
                    if (node instanceof DisplacementCircle) {
                        DisplacementCircle dc = (DisplacementCircle) node;
                        dc.setCenterY(ph * dc.y / h);
                    }
                }
            };
            pane.prefWidthProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> setX.accept(newval));
            pane.prefHeightProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> setY.accept(newval));
            
            reload.setOnAction(event -> {
                pane.getChildren().clear();
                List<Displacement> disList = Stream.generate(Displacement::new).limit(1200).collect(Collectors.toList());;
                disList.forEach(dis -> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementLine(dis, pane)));
                disList.forEach(dis -> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementCircle(dis, pane)));
                setX.accept(pane.getPrefWidth());
                setY.accept(pane.getPrefHeight());
            });
            
            VBox vbox = new VBox(reload, pane);
            Pane root = new Pane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            root.getChildren().add(vbox);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setWidth(1000);
            stage.setHeight(600);
            stage.show();
            
            pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(zoom.multiply(w));
            pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(zoom.multiply(h));
            pane.layoutXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().subtract(pane.prefWidthProperty()).divide(2.0));
            pane.layoutYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().subtract(pane.prefHeightProperty()).divide(2.0));
            
            pane.setOnScroll(scrollEvent -> {
                double delta = 0.1;
                double f = scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 1+delta : 1/(1+delta);
                zoom.set(zoom.get() * f);
            });
            
            reload.fire();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class DisplacementLine extends Line {

    final double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    
    public DisplacementLine(Displacement dis, Pane pane) {
        x1 = dis.x;
        y1 = dis.y;
        x2 = dis.x + dis.u;
        y2 = dis.y + dis.v;
        setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(dis.valid);
    }
}

class DisplacementCircle extends Circle {

    final double x, y;
    
    public DisplacementCircle(Displacement dis, Pane pane) {
        this.x = dis.x;
        this.y = dis.y;
        setRadius(1.5);
        setFill(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(dis.valid);
    }
}

class Displacement {

    final static Random rand = new Random();
    final double x, y, u, v;
    final boolean valid;
    
    public Displacement() {
        x = rand.nextDouble() * 1000;
        y = rand.nextDouble() * 600;
        u = rand.nextDouble() * 30;
        v = rand.nextDouble() * 15;
        valid = rand.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid GUI freezing take the long process off the application thread. To demonstrate it try this (demo only, not the best implementation):

```
        reload.setOnAction(event -> {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            new Thread(()->{
                List<Displacement> disList = Stream.generate(Displacement::new).limit(1200).collect(Collectors.toList());
                disList.forEach(dis ->Platform.runLater(()-> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementLine(dis, w, h, pane))));
                disList.forEach(dis ->Platform.runLater(()-> pane.getChildren().add(new DisplacementCircle(dis, w, h, pane))));
            }).start();

        });
```

Consider using a `Model` class to hold all the information used by the view. 
Also consider applying new displacements without reconstructing the lines and circles. 
Implementation of`DisplacementLine` with mutable displacement:

```
class DisplacementLine extends Line {

    private final SimpleDoubleProperty x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public DisplacementLine(Displacement dis, int w, int h, Pane pane) {

        x1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();     y1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        x2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();     y2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        setDisplacement(dis);
        startXProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty().multiply(x1).divide(w));
        startYProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty().multiply(y1).divide(h));
        endXProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty().multiply(x2).divide(w));
        endYProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty().multiply(y2).divide(h));
        setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(dis.valid);
    }

    public void setDisplacement(Displacement dis) {
        x1.set(dis.x);
        y1.set(dis.y);
        x2.set(dis.x + dis.u);
        y2.set(dis.y + dis.v);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right I can do that, in my real application it would be more work as the number of displayed shapes and other properties can change on reload.
I would consider that a workaround, but it does not solve the underlying problem that I see here, which is: Why does it take so long in the first place, why this "piling up" of work in the application after many reloads? What is it that seems to remain in the scene after getChildren().clear is called? I expected to get a "fresh" pane without any leftovers after clearing it?

Comment: _" What is it that seems to remain in the scene after getChildren().clear is called"_ nothing. It is simple enough to check it up yourself. Constructing 2400 shapes on every click does take time. Think of JavaFx Application as an application that runs on a single thread. When this thread is
busy with constructing thousands of shapes, it does not update the gui. The gui becomes unresponsive
(freezes). 
[Implementing long-running tasks on the JavaFX Application thread inevitably makes an application UI unresponsive](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Comment: Sure it takes time to construct 2400 shapes. But I believe the problem is somehow related to the bindings which update the coordinates. The observation is: Shapes get drawn real quick when "reloading", and that is each time. But after many reloads, upon triggering the mouse wheel, so when all the bindings for the coordinates have to be followed and resolved, THEN the freezing happens. Will investigate some more when I get to it.

Comment: _nothing_ is not the whole truth: while the nodes indeed are removed from the scenegraph (and no longer strongly reachable, making them eligable for gc), the listeners (registered via bindings from the nodes to the pane's properties) still linger. See my comments to the question.